# Why this code print white rectangle instead of red in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, rgb

I am doing some test with opengl and trying to draw a red rectangle. This is the code:

```
qDebug(__FUNCTION__);
float *rgbImage = (float *)malloc(width * height * 3 * sizeof(float));
float *rgbImagePtr = rgbImage;

qDebug("Initializing");
int y, x;
for(y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for(x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        *rgbImagePtr++ = 255;  // R
        *rgbImagePtr++ = 0;  // G
        *rgbImagePtr++ = 0;  // B
    }
}

// Generate false image

qDebug("Creating texture");
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
qDebug("drawing image");

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, rgbImage);
qDebug("drawing image finished");
```

When I run my example, I get white rectangle instead of red as I figure out when I am doing. What's the issue?

**EDIT 1**

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(256.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(256.0f, 256.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 0.0f, 256.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
```

Draw code added

Comment: Float data format should use values normalized in range 0..1.

Comment: You are only showing your texture binding code. There could be an issue with your drawing code... you might want to show that as well.

Comment: @Luca what is the right value of R channel then?

Comment: @MuertoExcobito Code added.

Comment: Where's your `glEnable` to turn on texturing?

Comment: @BenVoigt I added just before "Initializing" trace. Same result.

Comment: @jgd: I still don't see it.  Also, have you checked `glError()` ?

Comment: @ben voigt If there was an error, likely the draw would fail. It seems either the texture itself is white, or the texturing is not setup correctly. `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` should be called, and the texture data should be verified (@luca's suggestion that the data is invalid because it must be normalized.)

Comment: Your glTexImage2d is weird. The parameter internalFormat is... 3?

Comment: @Jerem what should be?

Comment: @MuertoExcobito I write glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) and the texture data is what you can see in code, creating rgbImage.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is, that your texture is considered incomplete due to the lack of mipmap layers. You either have to turn off mipmapping for the texture or supply a full stack of mipmap layers.

Additionally it seems you didn't enable the GL_TEXTURE_2D target on the active texture unit (required if using the fixed function pipeline).

Comment: I think I am turning off mipmapping with this:  `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);` I'm wrong?

Comment: @jgd: Indeed this call has the desired effect, but it must be called at the right time (with the texture bound, and depending on the bugs of the driver usually *after* the texture image has been loaded).

Comment: I try with it but the result it's the same. Maybe I'm generating RGB image bad?

Comment: @jgd: Even if you messed up the image generation you'd see something. OpenGL giving you white instead of a image is almost always the case if your texturing setup (texture parameters, upload, etc.) is incomplete or messed up.

Comment: Agree, but why is not complete?

Comment: @jgd: Hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code. A common mistake is that the texture loading code is called before there is a OpenGL context created and made current on the thread doing the texture loading. Since you're using Qt you should call your texture loading code from `initializeGL`

Comment: Is the name of method (initializeGL) important? The code that you can see above is all I make to draw in OpenGL surface.

Comment: If the texture is not mipmap complete, you get black, not white.

Comment: Means that I have a mipmap complete? Sorry but I'm newbie in OpenGL questions. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @jgd: `initializeGL` is a virtual member function of `QGLWidget`. BTW: `glTexImage2D` does not draw an image. It's uploading image data to OpenGL; you call it exactly one time per image to be used.

Comment: @RetoKoradi If you are using the fixed pipeline, I think you get white instead of black.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Indeed using the fixed function pipeline you get white if the texture setup is incorrect.

Comment: @datenwolf You're right. Well, more precisely, after checking the spec, it acts as if texturing is disabled. So you get whatever color you would get without texturing, based on the current color and lighting settings.

Comment: @jdg You made that `glTexParameter()` call after binding the texture?

Comment: @RetoKoradi: The idea behind these specs is, that you can use a GL_MODULATE texenv setting and "switch off" the texture without the whole object going black.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `glTexImage2d` has an incorrect `internalFormat` parameter:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, rgbImage);
                               ^-- here
```

The [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) says that it specifies number of color components in the texture, but it also says that the value should one of the enums given at the end of the page.

In your, case instead of 3, it should be `GL_RGB`.

Comment: Actually, the values 1 to 4 are explicitely allowed in legacy GL.  [OpenGL 2.1 specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec21.20061201.pdf), section 3.8.1 states "`internalformat` may (for backwards compatibility with the 1.0 version of the GL) also take on the integer values 1, 2, 3, and 4, which are equivalent to symbolic constants `LUMINANCE`, `LUMINANCE ALPHA`, `RGB`, and `RGBA` respectively.".